# PAR file frontend Pypar2 will not install

Tags: software-installation, software-sources

[image][image: Just my terminal output]

OK, so I am trying to get a front-end for PAR and PAR2 files, being an old Windhoos dog, working and miserably failed. Must I edit the sources file, do I need to get the pypar2 package and store it somewhere? Thanks for caring! Update: did try to install the .deb, the result is the darker screenshot....

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PyPar2](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/pypar2) is Python2 based, so this is why it is missed in modern Ubuntu versions.

It is still installable on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, 21.04 and 21.10 by manual download of dependencies using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pypar2/pypar2_1.4-7_all.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygtk/python-glade2_2.24.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vte/python-vte_0.28.2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vte/libvte9_0.28.2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vte/libvte-common_0.28.2-5ubuntu3_all.deb

wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
[ "$(lsb_release -cs)" == "impish" -o "$(lsb_release -cs)" == "hirsute" ] && sudo apt-get install ./python-cairo_1.16.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./pypar2_1.4-7_all.deb ./python-glade2_2.24.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python-vte_0.28.2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./libvte9_0.28.2-5ubuntu3_amd64.deb ./libvte-common_0.28.2-5ubuntu3_all.deb
```

Comment: Again it works great, obviously the recommendation I read, dates back some time, hence the fact that I missed the Python2 part.